# Why "Panchagavya" is considered holy in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, cows

In Hinduism Cows are considered holy.

Afflicting them with pain is considered as one of the gravest possible offences.

It is stated in Scriptures that cows are the best among animals,swan the best among birds and sweet the best among tastes.

The [Panchagavya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchagavya) is the mixture of five things obtained from a cow viz:
1)Dung(gomaya).
2)Urine(gomutra)
3)Milk
4)Curd
& 5)Ghee.

Apart from having ayurvedic significance the mixture is considered holy in Sanatana Dharma and is used for Abhisekhams of God's idols including the Shiva Lingam.

> Five products derived from a Cow viz. Gomoothra (cow urine), Gomaya
>   (cow-dung), Goksheera (cow milk), Godadhi (cow-curd), and Goghrutha
>   (cow ghee). Mixture of these five ingredients is known as Panchagavya.
>   Since time immemorial Panchagavya is used in all the traditional Hindu
>   rituals; considered as highly sacred and believed to provide spiritual
>   purification. It is also used in Hindu families for purification of
>   self as well as sprinkled across the house after asoucha.

[Source](http://bhargavasarma.blogspot.in/2012/07/symbolism-significance-of-number-five.html)

Question-Why "Panchagavya" is considered holy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is given in the [Parashara Smriti](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/13Parashara_Smriti.pdf) Chapter 11,Sloka 38 :

> **Brahmakurcho dahetsarvam Pradiptaagniribendhanam|| Pavitram Trishu Lokeshu Devata Bhiradhistitham||**
>
> **God Varuna is in the urine of the cow,Agni in cow dung,Vayu in curd,Moon God in curd and Sun God in the Ghee.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer mentions, the Parashara Smriti says that the god Varuna is in cow-urine, Agni is in cow-dung, Vayu is in curd, Soma in milk, and Ravi in ghee (which are the 5 components of Panchagavya).

But the wrong shloka has been quoted (although the translation of the correct shloka is mentioned). The numbering also seems to be off. In [this source](https://archive.org/details/ParasharaSmriti/page/n105/mode/2up) it is Chapter 11, shloka 39 while in [this source](https://archive.org/details/parasharsmritiguruprasadsharma/page/n111/mode/2up) it is Chapter 11, shloka 40.

The correct shloka is as follows -

> वरुणश्चैव गोमूत्रे गोमये हव्यवाहनः दध्निवायुः समुद्दिष्टः सोमः क्षीरे घृते रविः

(varuṇaścaiva gomūtre gomaye havyavāhanaḥ dadhnivāyuḥ samuddiṣṭaḥ somaḥ kṣīre ghṛte raviḥ)

> The god Varuna is in the urine of the cow ; the god of sacrificial fire in the cow-dung ; the god of wind in the curd ; the moon in the milk ; and the sun in the ghee.

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer