# Any other slokas suggesting drinking of cow urine

Tags: practice, identification-request, shloka, cows

The following statement from [Section 81, Anushasana Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b046.htm) of Mahabharata suggests drinking cow urine

> "Vyasa said, ... **One should for three days drink the hot urine of the
> cow**..."

In addition to this, please provide any other references that suggest the same.

Comment: Vyasa said we should drink. But didn't he explain, why? Do you have any info regarding "why"?

Comment: As per I know, no such reason was given in this context

Comment: @Rishabh Reason ('becomes cleansed of sins') is given....

Comment: People are downvoting valid Qs these days without giving any reasons. You shd complain to the Mods if u feel it is needed. @hanugm I hv already upvoted this Q before so can not compensate the useless downvote.

Comment: Yeah, some people are intentionally doing that and are biased towards some type of questions only. I am complaining @Rickross

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are numerous such verses in the Smritis. Consuming Panchagavyas (the five products obtained from a cow) is considered as an effective sin-cleansing remedy for a variety of sins.

Here are a few verses from various chapters of Parashara Smriti:

> **28. Urine of the cow, cow-dung, milk, curd, and ghee, these five are the five articles derived from a cow. They, and water in which the
>   kusa grass has been dipped, — are themselves pure, and therefore
>   purify the sin.**
>
> 24. A Krichchhra-santapana consists in eating cow-dung, cow's urine, milk, curd, ghee, and water in which kusa grass has been dipped, and
>       likewise a fast for a single night.
>
> Where a Brahman from ignorance follows the corpse of one who belongs
>   to the military caste, he becomes impure for a single night, and
>   purifies himself by eating the fivefold products of a cow. [These are,
>   milk, curd, clarified butter, cow's urine and cowdung.]
>
> 26. For drinking water raised from a well, into which a Chandala's pot has been dipped, purity may be restored by drinking for three nights
>       cow's urine in which half-ripe barley has been blended.
> 27. When a Brahman through ignorance chances to eat any food that belongs to one of the Chandala caste, he should purify himself by
>       living on half-ripe barley and cow's urine for ten nights
> 28. In case of association for a month or half a month, with persons belonging to the Chandala caste, purity returns by living on cow's
>       urine, wherewith unripe barley is mixed, during the period of half a
>       month

According to the Parashara Smriti,  Vedic deities reside in each of these five products from the cow.

> 8. **The god Varuna is in the urine of the cow** ; the god of sacrificial fire in the cow-dung ; the god of wind in the curd ; the
>      moon in the milk ; and the sun in the ghee

(Here is a related post : [Why is Panchagavya considered holy in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14934/why-panchagavya-is-considered-holy-in-hinduism))

Here are more such relevant verses from Manu Smriti:

> 11.90. A twice-born man who has (intentionally) drunk, through delusion of mind, (the spirituous liquor called) Sura shall drink that
>   liquor boiling-hot; when his body has been completely scalded by that,
>   he is freed from his guilt;
>
> **11.91. Or he may drink cow’s urine, water, milk, clarified butter or (liquid) cowdung boiling-hot, until he dies;**
>
> 11.212. (Subsisting on) the urine of cows, cowdung, milk, sour milk, clarified butter, and a decoction of Kusagrass, and fasting during one
>   (day and) night, (that is) called a Samtapana Krikkhra

Comment: 'drink that liquor boiling-hot; when his body has been completely scalded by that, he is freed from his guilt', 'boiling-hot, until he dies' - what kind of self-induced punishments are these? If this results in death, isn't that suicide which itself is a big sin? How is he supposed to free himself from guilt when he is no more?

Comment: It is not suicide.. 1.Scriptures which condemn suicide can not recommend the same.. 2. This is a form of punishment which is found in many Smritis for certain grave sins... For e.g for cohabiting with one's own mother such a punishment is prescribed in Parashara... @sv.

Comment: @Rickross I believe what is a substitute for such also does boiling it pure it of impurities obviously I am not thinking of doing such I find it repulsive, but I understand the sacredness of a cow.

Comment: No idea if that is the real reason behind boiling @Haridasa