# What does Parashara Smriti tell about untouchability?

Tags: smriti, parashara-smriti

What does Parashara Smriti tell about untouchability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like all other Smritis, the Parashara Smriti also is of the opinion that some human beings and some other beings are impure to touch.

Take a look at the following verse from the 6th chapter for example:

> 24. On seeing a Chandala, let him look at the sun without a moment's delay. For touching a Chandala, let him bathe with his clothing on.

Some more references are as follows:

> 27. A tree on a burning-ground, a funeral pile, pus, a Chandala, and a seller of the Soma plant ; having touched any of these, — a Brahman
>     should plunge into water with his clothing on. (Chapter 12)

> 20. While a Brahman has not washed himself after taking his meals, if he chances to be touched by another yet unwashed after a meal, or by a
>     dog, or by a Shoodra, he should fast for a single night, and then
>     swallow the five articles derived from a cow, whereby purity is
>     restored to- him.
> 21. If himself unwashed, he is touched by a Shoodra, who, however, is not unwashed, — the purification is to wash himself. If an unwashed
>     Shoodra touches an unwashed regenerate man, the latter must perform
>     the prajapatya penance.
>     (Chapter 7)

Comment: Can you keep all reference

Comment: You want to see more references? @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: Yes brother I want reference

Comment: No problem I have added a few more. Is that sufficient? @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: @Rickross I am curious are their 5 types of Chandalas and other Varnas and Mixed Varnas like their are 5 types of Brahmins, also what are the 5 articles of a cow?

Comment: Five articles of a cow are Panchagavya -- Gomutra, Gomaya, Ghee,milk and curd @Haridasa also there are various types of Varna Shankaras not limited to five.

Comment: For five products of the cow see this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14934/4732 @Haridasa

Comment: @Rickross understand why cow byproducts would be seen as holy, but aren't those unhealthy and bad for health?